# JDBC, Driver Class not found

Tags: database, macos, jsp, servlets, jdbc

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This error comes at line below:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Though the `Driver` class is in `com.mysql.jdbc`. This error is coming on my Mac where as, its working on `Windows`.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about your app. Presumably it's a webapp? Is it deployed in an app server like Jetty or Tomcat?

Comment: Its a webapp and I working with Tomcat. This error is coming when I am trying to login.

Answer (score 0):

As follows from MySQL specification (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) the driver class is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". So you have correct class name.

You need to include jar file, that contains this class (MySQL connector, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html) into your classpath.

If it is web application running on tomcat you could add connector to library directory (%CATALINA_HOME%/lib).

Comment: Could you please provide version of Tomcat you're using?